# Where can I find examples of the formatting/terminolgy/slang used in describing snowboarding routines in a competition scene?

Tags: creative-writing, technique, resources, research

I'm struggling to write an *accurate* description of a Snowboarding Competition, since I don't know where to access written accounts on the technique used as well as the correct terminology. I am busy researching the sport itself, but I really don't know how to correctly word it; i.e., use the correct slang, technical terms, the name of the technique performed and so forth.

I would appreciate it if someone could either explain to me what others do or point me in the right direction; i.e., What snowboarding magazines, websites or professional accounts of snowboarding techniques would help me understand (as watching Youtube videos doesn't *always* help you to actually *understand* what's happening).

I ask this, because after writing my own 'piece', I want to check a professional account in order to see if the format and wording of my writing would be correct.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE *Janika*! To explain a bit about what happened here: we are different from most other forums you will find on the internet in that we have a few quite strict rules about how questions are supposed to be worded and what they are about. The goal of StackExchange is to have a database of questions and answers that will be useful for future readers, which is why the community judged "What should I write?" questions to be off-topic, as they would helpful to you, but to nobody else.

Comment: I understood your question to be a request for examples that someone else has written before, which is why I have edited your question to include the [tag:resources] tag. If this was your intention you might want to [edit] your question to explain in more detail what you are looking for in such resources/examples so that it sounds less like "Please write something I could copy-paste" and more like "What do others do and where can I read about their techniques?" to get your question reopened.

Comment: An [edit] will automatically send your question to a special reopen review queue. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: I don't know why or by whom my comment was deleted, so I'm reposting it, because I meant it as serious help: **Go to a newsstand and buy a couple of snowboard magazines.** In the articles you can find examples of descriptions of people snowboarding (including during competitions) and the relevant terminology and "slang".

Comment: You can also just watch YouTube videos and listen to the narration of competitions, there are tons from the recent Olympics. If you hear the narrator use a term like Euro Carve (not that you would in a competition,  it's just the first thing that came to mind and so cool!) just YouTube that and you'll find a dozen videos showing you that trick. As for making it spellbinding... that's your job. If you've never experienced something, it's harder to write about. So, you could chat to some snowboarders who enter competitions and ask them how it feels. Just listen to them talk and get a feel.

Comment: Youtube search "XGames Snowboard" and just listen to the commentary.  It sounds like you might benefit from sports commentary in general, until you find a commentator or group of them that you like (and find spellbinding), then just apply the terminology of snowboarding to that.

Answer (score 5):

This is just good old fashioned research:

- Read Snowboarding magazines e.g [Snowboarder](https://www.snowboarder.com/), [Transworld SNOWboarding Magazine](https://snowboarding.transworld.net/), [Whitelines](https://whitelines.com/). There are plenty out there.
- Read Snowboarding how-to books (e.g. [Go Snowboard](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Go-Snowboard-Neil-McNab/dp/1405315741/) or [Snowboarding Freestyle Tricks, Skills and Techniques](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Snowboarding-Freestyle-Tricks-Skills-Techniques/dp/1408122847/)), watch "how to" snowboard videos, and read snowboarding travel books/advice like [Snowboarding the World](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Snowboarding-Footprint-Travel-Activity-Lifestyle/dp/1904777783/).
- Go to your library and and ask them for some books on Snowboarding, or any autobiographies written by famous snowboarders.
- Watch YouTube videos of snowboarding competitions and events e.g. the recent Winter Olympics. Pay close attention to the commentators, and how they speak.
- Listen to interviews of famous snowboarders e.g. Shaun White, Scotty Lago, Hannah Teter etc.
- Find names of famous or regular commentators, and focus on ones that you really like. Base your style on them. For example, Tim Warwood and Ed Leigh commenting for the BBC during the Winter Olympics were fairly highly praised (and sometimes criticised). Find out why they were praised and criticised.
- Read transcriptions of radio shows, videos if you can get hold of them. Transcribe them yourself so you get a feel for the language. Make notes of key phrases.
- Ask around your friends to see if they snowboard, or know people who snowboard, and interview them. Ask them questions.
- If you're able, go to local snowboarding beginner sessions. Speak to the instructors. Ask questions. Enroll in a course yourself, and get a feel for it.
- Go to shops that specialize in snowboarding gear, and go speak to the people who work there. There's probably someone who snowboards and can help answer questions, or introduce you to people.
- Give what you've written to the people you meet, and ask them to comment on what you've written, and how you've written it. Get them to critique it.

Basically, immerse yourself in their culture through reading, talking, listening. Do your research, and get a feel for it.

Note: I do not endorse any of the mentioned magazines or books, I'm just trying to help give advice on what to do.